# Uncontrolled MS Exchange db growth caused by a single mailbox

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I have an odd problem on one of the MS Exchange 2010 systems I manage. A single mailbox is causing rapid database growth. This is a problem we saw once before on the same system, only this time its a different mailbox.

We saw this a year or so back with a mailbox where, whatever database it was placed in, the database would grow rapidly (GBs/day). I discovered this by isolating the mailbox by itself. 
Get-MailboxDatabase -Status would indicate that the database did not have any free space, but its containing mailbox would only occupy, say, 2Gb of a 20GB database. 
If I moved the mailbox to a new database we would start again at 2GB and it would commence growing almost immediately. Sometimes growth would be slow, sometimes 10Gb overnight.

The user was not doing anything unusual and did not have a high volume of email.

We finally cured the problem by, rather drastically, exporting everything to a pst, deleting the mailbox, removing the profile in outlook, deleting the account on his phone and recreating everything. We had previously tried just recreating his outlook profile.

Now the problem has occurred again, only this time on a different mailbox. Since this has occurred twice I'd like to try and get to the bottom of the issue.

Can anyone suggest anything I can do to diagnose this or possible causes? What I've found by googling is rather vague and noone seems to be able to point to a cause.

Comment: Call MS Product Support and open a support case.

Comment: My first thought would be something like a corrupt calendar or to do list item on a connected device. Do these users connect with a smartphone or tablet? If so, does mailbox growth cease if you nuke the connection to the device.

Comment: apologies to the superuser admins for the mispost

Comment: I'm still trying to work this out. not sure I should rely on what the user tells me. These days anyone can set up a connection from their ipad at home and forget that its there, so I've been trying to work out how to pull this from exchange - no luck so far.